# Google-App-Engine urls based on handlers and methods

Tags: google-app-engine, routes, url-routing

Has anyone figured out an elegant way to do automatic routing in Google App Engine? I've ended up with a very long list of routes, i.e.

```
urls = routes.HandlerPrefixRoute(h+'index_handler.',[RedirectRoute(r'/',handler='IndexHandler')]),...
```

I'd like it so example.com/blog would automatically route to the blog handler and example.com/blog/method automatically routes to the blog.method method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out a pretty basic solution to routing with webapp2 and app engine.
I'm not going to post the whole solution here, but let me know if anybody wants to see it and I'll post it on github and send you a link.

I basically just use os to get my files in my handler directory and loop through the files:

```
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    if file.endswith(".py") and file != '__init__.py':
```

I use a pretty simple naming convention (i.e. file_name = FileName) so based on the files in the handler directory, I can create the routes dynamically for each.

I use decorators on methods that should be routed as well (i.e. the url handler/method would go to the handler file, Handler class and Handler.Method would be called). So I get all the methods for each class and if the class method has the attribute created by the decorator, route it!

So a for loop like this:

```
methods = inspect.getmembers(handlercls, predicate=inspect.ismethod)
methods = [x[1] for x in methods if hasattr(x[1], 'route')]

for method in methods:
    # Set some kwargs that I can then pass to a route (i.e. handler path, method to call, etc...)
```

Like I said and probably why nobody responded to this question, the entire solution is pretty long so if anybody wants, I'll put it up on GitHub and maybe people can add/contr. to it to improve it.